# Downloaded checksum mismatch Golang

Tags: go, checksum

I am trying to update an imported library published internally from my company. it works locally but when I push up to my CI machine I continuously get this error:

```
verifying organization.team/repo@v0.0.0-20211002191200-123ab4567890: checksum mismatch
    downloaded: h1:AC4Y8O95qWQoRDUIkeOOE03FOgyJYhZ2hR+3CDSn/Ngc=
    go.sum:     h1:j8IOQKqRRU/+IO9395vywb-JD0VesRqymC4h6PIkIKDO2A=
 
SECURITY ERROR
This download does NOT match an earlier download recorded in go.sum.
The bits may have been replaced on the origin server, or an attacker may
have intercepted the download attempt.
```

In this example `organization.team/repo` is a library originating from a Git repo in the same company account. My `go.mod` looks something like this:

```golang
module mypackage

go 1.15



require (
    organization.team/repo 0.0.0-20211002191200-123ab4567890
    ...etc...
}
```

Where the only change I've made is from the old version, basically I changed the go mod to have a newer version of the imported library, e.g:

instead of
`organization.team/repo 0.0.0-20211002191200-123ab4567890`
I had
`organization.team/repo 0.0.0-20210901131200-456cd7892890`

I'm not sure what to check at this point. I tried running a `go mod tidy`, as well as a `go clean -modcache` which other users seem to have had success with in a similar issue - and then a `go mod tidy` - and always the same issue. The checksum I get when I calculate it locally is always different than what the worker on the CI machine runs.

I've also tried running those commands and forcing it to the version of Go that the CI machines are on (1.15) by running `go1.15.15 mod tidy` and `go1.15.15 clean -modcache`, but my checksum remains the same whether I am locally using Go 1.15 or 1.16.

As others have pointed out in similar threads - git lfs is not at work here either, I don't have that installed. And when I did install it - same issue.

What makes it more confusing, is if I'm in the same pull request, I can upgrade the version of my `organization.team/repo`, get this error, and then I've tried actually downgrading back to the last working version, and the issue still persists.

Would appreciate some suggestions - I'm not even clear on what could possibly be going on.

Comment: Is the `go.sum` file checked into git? If so, are you sure it was updated with the code that was checked during that same commit version?

Comment: Yes, the `go.sum` is definitely checked in to Git. I'm sure it was updated too - as the build on the CI fails - citing the SHA used on my local build is not what's matching when it calculates its own SHA.

Comment: I have the same exact problem. I tried changing go and git versions. Nothing works. I calculated the checksum of the module folder using the go-checksum and it returns the what I see locally. @NateH06 were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this ?

Comment: @adsun and @bitbuoy , not really - but we narrowed it down to being an issue with git lfs. If you're using git lfs anywhere in particular on your repo, you may have to either uninstall it or turn it off and then do all your go get's or `go mod tidy` 'ing. Good luck!